# How can I use MLToolbox Meteolab?

Tags: matlab

I installed MLToolbox_R2013 by TortoiseSVN according to https://meteo.unican.es/trac/MLToolbox/wiki/Installation/MeteoLabSubversion. I use Matlab2013a and when I run `init` script I got the folowing mesage:

```
>> init
   To save the configuration, remember to save the path
```

I saved the MeteoLab path in `Set Path` and tried again run `init` script. But I got the same message. When I try

```
dmn=readDomain('Iberia_NCEP');
```

I get the error:

```
Error using getZonePath (line 8)
Directory Iberia_NCEP cannot be found in path Iberia_NCEP nor c:\Users  \Beata\Documents\MATLAB\MLToolbox_R2013\MeteoLab/../PatternsData/
```

Can someone write me why I get these messages and what I should to do for using this toolbox?

Comment: Can you somehow preallocate the save-file? Like the 'w' argument in fopen.

Comment: When I type `file = fopen('IIberia_NCEP');` I get `-1`, so it cannot open.

Comment: well, yes, because it does not exists. Add the extension to the file and append with 'w'. Since I do not know the file extension I'll just assume txt here: `file = fopen('IIberia_NCEP.txt','w');`

Comment: Iberia_NCEP contain nc directory in which there are some netcdf files. I tried: `file = fopen('NCEP_Z.nc','w');` and I got 3 so the netcdf files can be opened. But according to https://meteo.unican.es/trac/MLToolbox/wiki/Patterns/Loading `dmn=readDomain('Iberia_NCEP')` should be work.

Comment: I could solve the matter. I use `dmn=readDomain('c:\Users\Beata\Documents\MATLAB\MLToolbox_R2013\ModelData\NCEP\Iberia_NCEP')` Avoided my attention that  `dmn=readDomain('Iberia_NCEP')` is relative path to MLToolbox.

Answer (score 0):

Please go to this path:

**MLToolbox_R2013/ModelData/NCEP**

Then run command -

```
dmn=readDomain('Iberia_NCEP');
```